# Cast hours of day from 24 to 5

Tags: php, date

I want the day to be just 5 hours. Then all functions of php will apply on the new date .

The day is 5 hours not 24 .

For example:

start date/time: 14 oct 2017 8am
end date/time: 14 oct 2017 1pm

If I run this php command on this date " 14 oct 2017 8am"
$date->modify('+1 day');

Next day should be 
start date/time: 15 oct 2017 8am
end date/time: 15 oct 2017 1pm

Another example "14 oct 2017 11am" -> modify('+3 hours') giving "15 oct 2017 9am"

Is this possible ?

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: you can write your own logic for this. we can help you if you get stuck with that.

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP's DateTimes work with real-world dates and times, not with arbitrary numbers of hours in a day; you can't simply expect a magic setting that redefines the duration of a day so that standard PHP functions will change their behaviour accordingly, but you can write code to check if  the time is within your timeframe, and adjust accordingly.... however, SO isn't a free coding service to do that for you, but will help you fix errors in code where you have already tried yourself

Comment: This is a very broad requirement for this site. Possible answers would be either a) yes, there is a library with that feature (off-topic: resource requests tend to lead to spam); or b) yes, but you will need to write a lot of code (too broad: can't be answered in one short answer).

Comment: I imagine it is possible to do, you could potentially write a wrapper called `WorkDayDateTime` which extends `DateTime` and then override the  functionality where required, i.e. `->modify()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you all the code as it will probably be a lot of ifs.
But I think you can do this with an array as the "clock".

I created the array with just the hours but I think you need minutes to(?).
If the time is above 12 I use mod calculation to get the remainder of 13 and add that to 8.

```
$clock =["h" => [ "8" => 8,"9" => 9,"10" => 10, "11" => 11,"12" => 12]];

$time = 11;

Echo $clock["h"][$time]. "\n"; // 11

// +3 hours
$time +=3;
If($time > 12) $time = $time%13 +8; // and add one to day in date or strtotime
Echo $clock["h"][$time]. "\n"; // 9
```

https://3v4l.org/LdcJY

The date can probably be done with normal strtotime and/or date but hours (and minutes) may need a custom clock like above.

Edit:

A bit more detailed code.

```
$clock =["h" => [ "8" => 8,"9" => 9,"10" => 10, "11" => 11,"12" => 12]];

$dt = "14 oct 2017 11am";
$time = date("h", strtotime($dt));
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dt));

Echo $clock["h"][$time]. "\n";

// +3 hours
$time +=3;
If($time > 12){
    $time = $time%13 +8;
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dt)+86400);
}
Echo $clock["h"][$time]. "\n";
Echo date("d M Y ga", strtotime($date ." ". $time . ":00"));
```

https://3v4l.org/Yl1YA

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but you need to write your own logic and it's going to be fairly confusing to see what appears to be a standard builtin object but doesn't behave as such:

```
<?php

class TinyDayDateTime extends DateTime {
    public function modify($modify) {
        // Replace line below with full `DateTime::modify()` implementation
        parent::modify('2017-10-15 13:00:00');
    }
}

$d = new TinyDayDateTime('2017-10-14 08:00:00');
var_dump($d);
$d->modify('+1 day');
var_dump($d);
```

Perhaps you'd prefer to just add your own custom methods, such as `TinyDayDateTime::nextTinyDay()`.